# Facebook login/logout/check users in PHP Class powered by PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, authorization, facebook-php-sdk

I have PHP-Class to work with Facebook API:

```
class Social {
   private $name;
   private $context;
   private $tocken;

   public function check(){
     $this->tocken = $this->context->getAccessToken(); // get current tocken
     if (isset($_SESSION['fb_tocken']) AND !empty($_SESSION['fb_tocken'])){
        // session tocken not null
        if ($_SESSION['fb_tocken'] == $this->tocken){
           // session tocken = current tocken
           // update last active
           return true;
        } elseif ($this->tocken == APPLICATION_TOCKEN) {
          // current tocken == default tocken
          $this->logout();
        } else {
          // current tocken <> default tocken
          $this->logout();
        }
     } else {
        // session tocken is null
        if ($this->tocken == APPLICATION_TOCKEN){
          // current tocken is default
          return false;
        } else {
          // current tocken is not default
          if ($this->getUserInfo()){
             // user registered - login action
             if ($this->login())
                return true;
             else
                return false;
          } else {
             // register new user
             if ($this->register()){
                if ($this->login()){
                   return true;
                } else
                   return false;
             } else
                return false;
          }
        }
  }
   }
   // ...
};
```

If user used alogritm:

1 - Login in facebook
2 - Login in application
3 - Logout from facebook
4 - Login in facebook
5 - Open application

Application Problem:

after fifth step my app can't authorize a user. But if user press 'refresh' he become authorized.

Comment: @Roddie I'am modify this class, now it works. But there is a problem -  IE x - not saved cookie from Iframe.How to overcome this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct behviour - but impossible to confirm without the rest of your code (i.e. the bit that grabs the token).

What happens is that when a user logs out, the current token (that you have stored in your session) becomes invalid. The user logs back into Facebook, you need to get the new token, and that's not going to happen automtically - but when you do a refresh, I presume your code getAccessToken() (not shown above) will grab the new token.

The simplest fix is to add a listener in Javascript for logging in and out. You can find the [details here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) and you need the auth.login handler. When you have that triggered, simply refresh the page.

There are other options using Javascript tot pump the new token to a PHP listener that can update your session behind the scenes.

Comment: Robbie $this->tocken = $this->context->getAccessToken(); // get current tocken

Comment: You'll need to debug the rest of your code then - this works just fine in IE so you have something else that's stopping Javascript scripts from running, probably, or your refresh instruction is wrong. But we can't say more than that without seeing code.

Comment: all scenario worked. Not worked registration user if the user from canvas.

application goes crazy in this scenario.

Comment: This approach will work in canvas too, Sri it sounds like to have a looping redirect. Impossible to say though without seeing code. Id you're still stuck, create a new question and upload the code you have regarding the redirects.